# exibir listview na mesma activity após consulta

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho esse layout de consulta com um Listview:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de marcar o `RadioButton` e escrever o parâmetro de pesquisa gostaria que a lista aparecesse com os dados do banco de dados (detalhe, tenho um `Listview` que retorna todos os dados cadastrados no banco funcionando normalmente), porem eu clico em pesquisar e não acontece nada, nem retorno de erros, estou usando o mesmo `adapter` da minha outra lista que esta funcionando normalmente.

Será que o problema é porque o `listview` esta na mesma Activity da consulta?

**Minha Activity de consulta:**

```
public class ConsultaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Livro livro = new Livro();
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private EditText editText;
private ListView lvConsulta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgOpcoes);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtconsulta);
    lvConsulta = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvConsulta);
}

public void consultar(View view) {
    LivroCRUD livroCRUD = new LivroCRUD(this);
    try {
        switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.rbtnTitulo:
                    livro.setTitulo(editText.getText().toString());
                    List<Livro> listaTitulo = livroCRUD.buscarTitulo(livro);
                    lvConsulta.setAdapter(new LivroAdapter(this, listaTitulo));
              Toast.makeText(this, "passou pelo processo......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.rbtnAutor:
                    livro.setAutor(editText.getText().toString());
                    List<Livro> listaAutor = livroCRUD.buscarAutor(livro);
                    lvConsulta.setAdapter(new LivroAdapter(this, listaAutor));
                break;
            case R.id.rbtnEditora:
                    livro.setEditora(editText.getText().toString());
                    List<Livro> listaEditora = livroCRUD.buscarEditora(livro);
                    lvConsulta.setAdapter(new LivroAdapter(this, listaEditora));
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possivel realizar a consulta....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

**Um dos métodos de pesquisa por parâmetros:**

**EDIT:** alteração do metodo consulta após dicas do @ramaral

```
//BUSCAR POR TITULO
public List<Livro> buscarTitulo(String titulo) throws Exception{
    List<Livro> lista = new ArrayList<Livro>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","titulo","autor","editora"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query("livro", colunas, "titulo= ?",new String[]{titulo},null,null,null);
    //Percorre o cursor se tiver registos
    //Se não for nulo move para o primeiro registo
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Livro livroTitulo = new Livro();
            //retornar os valores e adiciona na lista
            livroTitulo.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            livroTitulo.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
            livroTitulo.setAutor(cursor.getString(2));
            livroTitulo.setEditora(cursor.getString(3));
            lista.add(livroTitulo);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return (lista);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, o problema não será ter a *ListView* na mesma Activity.

Existem "problemas" no código mas, à partida, não são razão para não funcionar como quer.
Digo "à partida" porque não tenho uma visão geral dele.

Os "problemas" que encontro são:

- Não há razão para passar um *Livro* ao método `buscarTitulo()`. Ele deve receber uma *String*, com o Título a pesquisar.
- A cláusula *WHERE* deve ser construída usando parâmetros
- Deve testar se o curso não é nulo antes de o utilizar.

**Buscar por título:**

```
public List<Livro> buscarTitulo(String titulo) throws Exception{
    List<Livro> lista = new ArrayList<Livro>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","titulo","autor","editora"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query("livro",
                             colunas,
                             "titulo = ?", new String[] {titulo()},
                             null, null, null);

    //Percorre o cursor se tiver registos
    //Se não for nulo move para o primeiro registo
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Livro livroTitulo = new Livro();
            //retornar os valores e adiciona na lista
            livroTitulo.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            livroTitulo.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
            livroTitulo.setAutor(cursor.getString(2));
            livroTitulo.setEditora(cursor.getString(3));
            lista.add(livroTitulo);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Lembre que para ser encontrado algum registo tem de escrever o título tal como foi gravado.

Considere utilizar *MATCH* em vez de `=` para procurar o(s) Título(s).
A seguinte *query* trará todos os livros cujo título começa pela *String* passada ao método(variável `titulo`).

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("livro",
                         colunas,
                         "titulo MATCH ?", new String[] {titulo + "*"},
                         null, null, null);
```

Verifique se não esqueceu de declarar o evento `onClick` do botão como sendo o método `consultar()`

Comment: o listview continua não aparecendo, para testar eu coloquei para exibir uma mensagem na tela dentro do case de consultar titulo do switch, e quando aperto o botão consultar a mensagem e exibida na tela, o que eu acho que significa que passou por todo o processo de consulta dentro do case, alterei minha postagem para mostrar, sera que tenho que fazer alguma operação fora do switch case?

Comment: Veja se ele entra dentro do bloco `do/while` do método `buscarTitulo()`

Comment: consegui arrumar, esta exibindo normalmente refiz o metodo `query` passando `titulo` ao invés de `titulo()`.